# How to sum matrix values based on specific indexing row with arbitrary indices in R

Tags: r, matrix

Consider the following matrix:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
c1    2    5    1    1    5    2
c2    4    1    7    3    3    2
```

I'd like to sum the values corresponding to each index in the first row without having to use a loop and without having to fiddle with the order of the indexing row (i.e. the first row).
So for instance in this particular case, the output should read:

```
        [,1] [,2] [,3]
    c1    2    5    1
    c2    6    4    10
```

It's fine if the matrix can't be truncated as in above. Will appreciate any help!

Comment: `tapply(m[2,], m[1,], FUN = sum)`

Comment: It worked! Thanks.